# How do i use brand fontawesome icon in angular

Tags: angular, font-awesome-5

I can't use font awesome brand icons in my component
I try to import it, but there is't any icons.

```
import {faTelegram} from "@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome"; // Has no exported member
```

But as we can see brand icon is available in fontawesome-5
https://fontawesome.com/icons/telegram?style=brands

How do i use this icon!?

Comment: how could you just  use in icon in ts file

Comment: You are importing but are you using it anywhere?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Do your self a favor, at least read the doc's first page.

Brands are imported from

```
'@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons' // or pro-brands-svg-icons
```

[The documentation (first page)](https://github.com/FortAwesome/angular-fontawesome/blob/527737b613d709ddfabc60000fb06c1776617502/docs/usage/using-other-styles.md#brand-icons) has an in depth usage example

```
import { faTwitter } from '@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons';

// Add an icon to the library for convenient access in other components
library.add(faTwitter);
```

---

```
<fa-icon [icon]="['fab', 'twitter']"></fa-icon>
```

Comment: You don't need to mess with the `library` - after importing you can just assign the imported icon to field on the component (`faTwitter=faTwitter;`) and load it (`<fa-icon [icon]="faTwitter"></fa-icon>`)- as they explain in the docs.

Comment: @Guss putting the icons in the library once seems to be much better than duplicating them into several components, don't you think?

Comment: good point. In my case I'm only using it in one component (possibly other icons in other components, but no duplication at this point). I do want to note the warning at https://github.com/FortAwesome/angular-fontawesome/blob/master/docs/usage/icon-library.md#using-the-icon-library : "This has long-term maintenance implications, specifically, this means that if someone accidentally removes the icon from your icon library the component that uses it will break."