# How can I use a font awesome brand icon in an angular component?

Tags: angular, font-awesome, font-awesome-5, angular-fontawesome

I am trying to use a Font Awesome Brand Icon in my Angular 10 application.
I have installed fontawesome and attempted to import it by using:

```
import { faDiscord } from '@fortawesome/fontawesome-free-brands';
```

in my component.
I have then assigned faDiscord to a property and am trying to use it like this in my html:

```
<fa-icon [icon]="faDiscord"></fa-icon>
```

However, my component is now stuck on loading, how can I fix this? Already seen this question: [How do i use brand fontawesome icon in angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57920352/how-do-i-use-brand-fontawesome-icon-in-angular)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, run the following commands:

```
npm install @fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core
npm install @fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons
npm install @fortawesome/angular-fontawesome@0.7.0
```

You should change the version number in the last command according to your Angular version. [See the docs](https://github.com/FortAwesome/angular-fontawesome#compatibility-table).

> Font Awesome icons are separated into styles, which are shipped in
> separate packages to meet different needs and to reduce individual
> packages size. To use an icon you'll need to install a package which
> contains it.

In your case, you are trying to use an `icon` which is available inside `Brands Style` package. [Discord Icon](https://fontawesome.com/icons/discord?style=brands)

[image]

So run the following command:
[See Here](https://github.com/FortAwesome/angular-fontawesome/blob/master/docs/usage/using-other-styles.md#using-other-styles).

```
npm install @fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons
```

Now import `FontAwesomeModule` in AppModule:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { FontAwesomeModule } from '@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FontAwesomeModule
  ],
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

In your component `blabla.components.ts`, create a new variable and assign `faDiscord` to it:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { faDiscord } from '@fortawesome/fontawesome-free-brands';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  faDiscord  = faDiscord;
}
```

Now in your `app.component.html`:

```
<fa-icon [icon]="faDiscord"></fa-icon>
```

Here is a [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fontawesome-sample-mr3ae2?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Comment: For some reason my app gets stuck on loading :(

Comment: Have you added `FontAwesomeModule` to your app module ?

Comment: Where would that be imported from?

Comment: in your app.module.ts file, add  `FontAwesomeModule ` to the import part.
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FontAwesomeModule
  ],

Comment: https://github.com/FortAwesome/angular-fontawesome#usage

Comment: I think Ive got my imports all messed up, my app module is looking like this

Comment: What is your Angular version?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220272/discussion-between-kalek-and-m-fuat-nuroglu).

Comment: Please, Can you accept my answer if it was helpful?

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution provided by **angular-fontawesome** has limits when I worked with CMS that renders the SVG icons dynamically based on the content. 
There was no way to import these icon in advance.
I came up with another way to render SVG FontAwesome

```
    <fa-svg prefix="far|fas|fab"
        name="..."
        title="Text to show when hovered"
        alt="Text alternative for screen reader"
        cssClass="..."
        shrink="8"
        grow="16"
        up="32"
        down="32"
        left="16"
        right="16"
        rotate="45"
        flip="horizontal|vertical|both"
        animation="pulse|spin"
        inversed="true"
        maskPrefix="far|fas|fab"
        maskName="..."></fa-svg>
```

This library can render both (FontAwesome 5) WebFont and SVG  icons with Angular

https://www.npmjs.com/package/@ui4ngx/fontawesome

[Demo](https://tuyenttran.github.io/ngx-fontawesome/)

This uses HTML templates instead of Javascript rendering. 
It provides the same features as **angular-fontawesome** library does